# Video recording - No audio right first time after permissions required

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, ios-camera

I've implemented video recording using AVFoundation and I encountered a really strange issue:
The first thing I do, in ViewDidAppear I check/request access for video & microphone. If I start recording right after that, my video has no audio at all.
This happens only when the access Alert is shown - and I start recording.
If the access was already provided - and I do start recording, everything is ok.
Has anyone encountered something like this?
I tried everything.

Comment: Is there no audio or is there audio but it's silent?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman - There seems to be some audio .. but it is silent. This happens only the first time after I give permissions to the camera & microphone. If I init the session again, it works every time.